# Could the scripts be improved in places (or at least this one specific place)?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I understand Stack site's *engines* are *beasts*, with a *truly vast* amount of shenaniganary going on - many things being checked, updated, changed on the fly, DB updates, etc.

So this is posted *tentatively* knowing it might just be a case of "it has to be that way because of X".

---

The following image is from my [profile activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/230506/james?tab=topactivity), and the two sections are next to each other in the profile, as they appear in the image:

[image: wasted-opportunity]

On "*face value*" this seems like a wasted opportunity.

The two sections are required to show data for essentially the same thing on the same page area - "total posts edited".

Would it be possible for those two things to draw data from the same source?
Ideally the Badge data would use the data retrieved for the Impact section, so the Badge data would actually be up to date.

---

I know this might mean an entirely new script to check *if X badge is present and if so use data from Impact else etc etc*, which might be more work than it is now.

So this is just a discussion point from an observation, not a complaint, or request really - unless it would be practical/feasible to do.

If practical to do, the same could be done for other badges which are related to the Impact area.

e.g.

1. Impact data "helpful flags" *used for* Track "Marshal" badge
2. Impact data "votes cast" *used for* Track "Civic Duty" badge

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're not drawing data from two places. They're drawing data based on **different criteria** - both numbers are correct, but they're counting different things. Not every one of those edits actually counts towards the badge. (To be fair, I don't know the exact criteria for counting in the impact section, but the tooltip suggests it's just edits on other people's posts).

> - Edits on deleted posts do not count
> - Edits to your own posts do not count
> - Edits to community wiki posts do count
> - Edits that consist only of tag changes do not count
> - Tag wiki edits do count
> - Edits you suggest before gaining full edit privileges do count, once approved
> - Each edited post counts only once, regardless of how many additional edits you may submit

From the mighty [list of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)

Comment: :facepalm: In which case I refer to my opening paragraph - there's so much to know around here :) Thanks animuson. I presume it'll be the same for the other badges I mentioned then?

Comment: The flags badge should update immediately when you get new helpful flags. At least, I'm not aware of anything that causes them not to by in-sync. The votes badges have all sorts of weird caching around them so I'm not gonna touch that one.